# The image with the jpg extension that I use in my nuxt project is uploaded to the page too late. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js

```
<div class="personal-image-wrapper">
  <img width="50" height="50" src="@/assets/images/personal_image.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

In my Nuxt project, I have an images folder under the assets directory. I want to use an image from this folder as a profile picture with dimensions of 50x50. However, this image is loading very slowly.

When I check the network tab in DevTools, I see that the file named personal_image has been in the 'stalled' state for a long time. What is the exact reason for this?

[Network tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPUOn.png)

I tried using the NuxtImg component, but I encountered the same issue there as well. Additionally, I faced problems such as images not appearing due to them being searched under the _ipx folder.

Comment: What is the file size and dimensions of the JPG file that loads slowly?

Comment: @MartinBrown 150x150 and 30,0 KB